# Chart.js : scaleStartValue from highest to lowest

Tags: chart.js

I am using Chart.js to render a line graph and I want my data to be plotted the reverse way, i.e the highest number to be shown at the bottom and the lowest to be shown at the top. I am able to achieve this by setting a negative scaleSteps but the actual labels on the Y-axis are lost. Is there a way to have those labels as well. Please see the sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/7z5e87he/

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
        scaleShowGridLines: false,
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleStartValue: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleSteps: -6,        
        responsive:true}); ;
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

There's no support for inverting the y-axis in chartjs:
https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/579

You can fake it by inverting your data set (although axis labels won't match up):

```
var inverted = [8, 8, 9, 7, 7, 7, 5, 4],
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, inverted);

inverted.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    inverted[idx] = max - val;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/az2u51gj/